# Fatal error: Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\app\Validation\Forms\OrderForm.php on line 12

Tags: php, validation

I installed respect/validation with composer but when using it with my work I get this error when loading the page.

"Fatal error: Class 'Respect\Validation\Validator' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cart\app\Validation\Forms\OrderForm.php on line 12"

This is the code of the page it is on:

```
<?php

namespace Cart\Validation\Forms;

use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

class OrderForm
{
    public static function rules()
    {
        return[
            'email' => v::email(),
            'name' => v::alpha(' '),
            'address1' => v::alnum(' -'),
            'address2' => v::optional(v::alnum(' -')),
            'city' => v::alnum(' '),
            'postal_code' => v::alnum(' '),
        ]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like your autoloader isn't recognizing the `use Respect\Validation\Validator` statement. Have you made sure that the package is on a path that the autoloader can see?

Comment: Is the autoloader `vendor/autoload.php` loaded?

Comment: My autoloader has loaded everything else that I have installed like Laravel, Twig, PHP-DI etc but not when I installed Respect Validation. To be clear now, When I install a package through terminal it downloads to my main directory (C drive) and not the directory I need it in (htdocs/cart/vendor), forcing me to move it manually. Would I maybe need to update the composer.json file from the main directory (C Drive) to recognize Respect and then move it where I need it (htdocs/cart)?